# Auto load child items from immediate parent based on XML attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file which looks like...

```
<Modules>
    <Module Title='Mod1' Attr2='' Attr3=''>
        <Functions>
            <Function Title='Fun1' Attr2=''>
                <SubFunctions>
                    <SubFunction Title='SubFun1' Attr2='' />
                    <SubFunction Title='SubFun2' Attr2='' />
                </SubFunctions>
            </Function>
            <Function Title='Fun2' Attr2='' />
            <Function Title='Fun3' Attr2='' />
         </Functions>
</Module>
<Module Title='Mod2' Attr2='' Attr3=''>
    <Functions>
    </Functions>
</Module>
<Module Title='Mod3' Attr2='' Attr3=''>
    <Functions>
    </Functions>
</Module>
```

I have been trying to write a generic function based on recursive in nature using LINQ and XML in C# but have not able to get hold on making the function as generic as possible.

What I have currently is my functions loads all the data related "Module", hence the count is 3 as per above XML data. When the user selects 'Mod1' the very first "Module", it should load all respective data which is under this 'Mod1' i.e. Fun1, Fun2, Fun3. Again if the user selects Fun1, it should load all the data under this 'Fun1' i.e. SubFun1, SubFun2 etc.

**PLEASE NOTE: I don't want to hardcode any XML tags in my C# application.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for `Elements()`...

Comment: @It'sNotALie. any sample codes you can share please?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hardcode the names of the tags, we should make an assumption about the XML structure. According to your example it seems that there are two kinds of elements:

1. "Container" element. Modules, Functions, SubFunctions. Which can contains zero or more "Data" element
2. "Data" element. Module, Function, SubFunction. Which can contain zero or one "Container" element and always has a "Title" attribute which is used for selection.

Note that "Title" attribute name is hardcoded unless you use customized name. Your decisions.

The code can be generic, as we don't care about the names of the Elements, but only their relation.
As you described, user chooses the selected element gradually, following this requirement I would propose the following solution:

MyXmlReader - class that supplies the access to the XML file
DataElement - class that contains data about the queries Element, including its child elements

```
 class MyXmlReader
{
    // refference to current list element
    XmlNode currentListElement = null;
    XmlDocument xml;

    // load file, initialize  and return data that contains info ablut
    // the first level elements names
    public DataElement Load(string path)
    {
        xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(path);
        Init();
        DataElement result = new DataElement();
        result.SubTitles = GetChildTitles();
        return result;
    }

    // Initialize the reader to read from the beggining
    public void Init()
    {
        currentListElement = xml.DocumentElement;
    }

    // Get next child
    public DataElement GetNext(string title)
    {
        string tempTitle;

        foreach (XmlNode child in currentListElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            DataElement result = null;

            if (child.Attributes["Title"].Value == title)
            {
                // create object that contains the data about the child nodes Titles
                result = new DataElement();
                result.Title = child.Attributes["Title"].Value;

                if (child.FirstChild != null) // means no child nodes
                {
                    currentListElement = child.FirstChild;

                    // add subelements subtitles
                    result.SubTitles.AddRange(GetChildTitles());
                }
                return result;


            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public List<string> GetChildTitles()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        foreach (XmlNode child in currentListElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            result.Add(child.Attributes["Title"].Value);
        }
        return result;
    }


}


// add any other data to this class
// that you need about the element you return
class DataElement
{
    public List<string> SubTitles = new List<string>();
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
// test
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyXmlReader reader = new MyXmlReader();
        DataElement data = reader.Load("Data.xml");

        // Generic test:

        // get first module
        data = reader.GetNext(data.SubTitles[0]);
        // get first function 
        data = reader.GetNext(data.SubTitles[0]);
        // get first sub-function 
        data = reader.GetNext(data.SubTitles[0]);         


        // you can write test with hardcode nodes names like this:
        reader.Init();
        // get first module
        data = reader.GetNext("Mod1");
        // get first function 
        data = reader.GetNext("Fun1");
        // get first sub-function 
        data = reader.GetNext("SubFun1");  

        Console.Read();
    }
```